# No 'Save Password' Prompt by any browser for my form

Tags: html, forms, zend-framework

My form is attached below, and I have tried many things I've found in other forums, but to no avail. I cant get the browser to prompt a 'Save Password'. Where am I going wrong. Hope someone can help. Thanks.

```
<form id="frmlogin" action="/index" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" autocomplete="on">
        <label id="landing_username" class="required" for="username">Username/Email</label>
        <input id="landing_username" name="username" type="text" value="" name="username" />
        <label id="landing_password"  class="required" for="password">Password</label>
        <input id="landing_password"  name="password" type="password" value="" name="password" />
        <submit id="loginbtn" onclick="LoginFun()" type="submit" name="loginbtn">Login</submit>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to clean the HTML a bit, maybe it helps:

```
<form id="frmlogin" action="/index" method="post">
    <label id="landing_username" class="required" for="username">Username/Email</label>
    <input id="username" name="username" type="text"  />
    <label id="landing_password"  class="required" for="password">Password</label>
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" />
    <input id="loginbtn" onclick="LoginFun()" type="submit" name="loginbtn" value="Login" />
 </form>
```

- the form attribute `enctype` is by default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` so you don't need to specify it
- the labels `for` attribute should contain the `id`, not the `name` of the associated input
- element IDs should be unique
- the attribute `name` is defined twice for both password and username
- the attribute `autocomplete` is by default `on`
- the input `value` is not required, so you don't need to add it to the inputs with an empty string
- the submit button should be an input of type submit

Some of these changes are only optimizations and the code could work fine without them, but others, such as ensuring the unique id of each tag, are fixes and they are strongly recommended even if the browser displays the form properly.